# Non-overlapping regions of multidimensional space

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'd like to pick points in a multidimensional space such that:

- They minimize a distance function between the point and others in it's neighborhood
- They be sufficiently apart from each other so that their neighborhoods don't overlap

How can I solve this?

Would a greedy "pick the most dense neighborhood" and iterate approach be optimal? I really don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sample points in this multi dimensional space ? If so I would suggest you to fit a multi variate gaussian. With octave or similar software you can easily find the mean and covariance matrix for the gauss distribution.

Then by randomly sampling this gaussian distribution function, you'd get points close to each other.

This may give you an alternative idea about how to generate random points in multi dimensional space near your samples.

Good luck with your work.